# Conditionally construct a `boost::optional` member variable on class constructor member initializer list

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a non-copyable and non-moveable class `Person`:

```
struct Person
{
  int m_icNum;

  explicit Person(int icNum) : m_icNum(icNum) {}
  Person (const Person & other) = delete;
  Person (Person && other) = delete;
};
```

And another class `PersonContainer`:

```
struct PersonContainer
{
  boost::optional<Person> m_person;

  explicit PersonContainer(int icNum)
  : m_person( icNum >= 0 ? Person(icNum) : boost::none) // this does not compile because the two operands of ternary operator ? must have the same type
  {}
};
```

Apparently I cannot construct `m_person` using ternary expression in the initializer list. An alternative is to construct it in the ctor body using `boost::in_pace`, but I wonder if there is a nice way to construct it in the initializer list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by @kabanus' comment, this can be achieved using [boost::in_place_init_if](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_/detailed_semantics___optional_values.html#reference_optional_in_place_init_if):

```
struct PersonContainer
{
  boost::optional<Person> m_person;

  explicit PersonContainer(int icNum)
  : m_person(boost::in_place_init_if, icNum >= 0, icNum)
  {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly specify the ternary operator return type to be `boost::optional<Person>`.

```cpp
explicit PersonContainer(int icNum)
  : m_person( icNum >= 0 ? boost::optional<Person>{Person(icNum)} : 
                           boost::optional<Person>{boost::none}) 
  {}
```

Comment: In my question `Person` is non-copyable and non-moveable

Comment: You should be able to combine this with [`in_place_init`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_/detailed_semantics___optional_values.html#reference_optional_in_place_init) to make it work, @Danqi : `boost::optional<Person>(boost::in_place_init, icNum)`

Comment: @kabanus Nice. Actually I find there is even an `in_place_init_if` tag, which is exactly what I need. Thanks for showing the way:
`: m_person(boost::in_place_init_if, icNum >= 0, icNum)`

Comment: @Danqi, perfect, I was unfamiliar!